# DoctrineParamConverter error after fresh symfony skeleton website installation

Tags: symfony

I installed symfony 5.1 but when I run application following error occured.

Argument 1 passed to Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\DoctrineParamConverter::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry or null, instance of Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry

Comment: same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63576790/clear-cache-error-after-installing-api-platform-com).

Comment: should be [solved now](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/37935).

Comment: Maybe then a duplicate issue I just reported: https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/issues/665

Answer (score 1):

you just need to upgrade your composer with command "composer upgrade".

Try it and give feedback.

Comment: Thank you, this solved an identical problem I've got here!