# symfony error: DoctrineParamConverter::__construct() must be an instance of ManagerRegistry

Tags: symfony

Using symfony, while attempting to run the login form I get:

```
Argument 1 passed to Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\DoctrineParamConverter::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry or null, instance of Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry given,
```

`composer.json`:

```
{
    "type": "project",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.1.3",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "composer/package-versions-deprecated": "^1.11",
        "doctrine/annotations": "^1.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.1",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^2.2",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.7",
        "laminas/laminas-code": "^3.4",
        "laminas/laminas-eventmanager": "^3.2",
        "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^4.3",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
        "symfony/asset": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/console": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/form": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/http-client": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/intl": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/mailer": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/process": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/property-access": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/property-info": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/serializer": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/translation": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/validator": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/web-link": "4.4.*",
        "symfony/yaml": "4.4.*",
        "twig/extra-bundle": "^2.12|^3.0",
        "twig/twig": "^2.12|^3.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "symfony/browser-kit": "^4.4",
        "symfony/css-selector": "^4.4",
        "symfony/debug-bundle": "^4.4",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.21",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^5.1",
        "symfony/stopwatch": "^4.4",
        "symfony/twig-bundle": "^4.4",
        "symfony/var-dumper": "^4.4",
        "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "^4.4"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "paragonie/random_compat": "2.*",
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php71": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php70": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php56": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "4.4.*"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new.  I followed all the steps but I'm stuck here.

Comment: it looks really weird that it would screw up the auto-wiring. have you run `bin/console cache:clear` yet?

Comment: i tried it , same error , now even for http://127.0.0.1:8000/ i got this error message

Comment: Hi, I've got an identical error message, and I was able to solve it according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63661241/3718031